# Пользование Sublime Text 2 без регистрации

Tags: sublime-text

Можно ли пользоваться Sublime Text 2 без регистрации серийного номера? Просто у них на сайте скачивание в свободном доступе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно, но он будет иногда предлагать купить себя. Что не есть обязательным.

Comment: Не иногда, а примерно раз в 3-10 сохранений.

Comment: Иногда во время сохранения. Но уж точно не так часто.

Comment: Ступил, я пользуюсь SFTP плагином, вот он и просится раз в 3-10 сохранений.

Comment: разве в сети кряков?

Comment: @Insider, а если гвоздь забить надо будет - придётся украсть молоток?  Хотя стоимость ST какая-то уж совсем заоблачная

Comment: @xEdelweiss зачем же? Я считаю.. если это не коммерчиское использование, а просто в виде обучения или он купит её потом(после окончания разработки).. почему бы не воспользоваться таким?